# Trying to center a flex section in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am just starting to learn HTML and CSS with Bootstrap 4 and have run into an issue.

I am trying to center a CTA section that uses the flex function to lay out the columns. Somehow, despite long research, I have not been able to find a way to center it as it always seems slightly to the right or left.

I assume that I have overlooked something, any directions would be great, even if it is something that I can improve on.

[This is what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZtvK.png) with this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#"><div class="cf col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
            <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded"></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><div class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
            <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded"></a>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><div class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
            <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
    .cta {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img.cta {
  opacity:100; background:white;
  -o-transition:opacity .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition:opacity .2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:opacity .2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:opacity .2s ease-out;
  /* ...and now override with proper CSS property */
  transition:opacity .2s ease-out;
}

img.cta:hover { opacity:0;} 

.cf {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.cf img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

.cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.cta-text {

}
```

Comment: i would suggest you present your entire html code. @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **a** tag might cause problem here. First of all, it is not correctly closed.

Try writing this:

```
<a href="#" class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
   <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
   <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded">
</a>
```

Second, I believe it's always better to have it 'inside' the div you're trying to center instead of outside. This is because  tags are not considered 'display: block' by default.

or

```
<div class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
   <a href='#'>
     <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
   </a>
   <a href='#'>
     <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded">
   </a>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.d-flex > a {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly nested, i think you should start from there. In order for it to work, html tags most correspond.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <a href="#">
       <div class="cf col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
          <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
           <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
           <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
        <div class="cf col-4  d-flex justify-content-center">
           <img class="cta bottom" src="img/home/dev-more.png" class="rounded">
           <img class="cta top" src="img/home/development.png" class="rounded">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```